# Reading string from XML; can't set checkBox.Checked

Tags: c#, xml

I will read the `CheckBox.Value` (True or false) from my xml file but it does not work.

I use `CheckBox3.Checked = reader.Value;` this gives a error

What's wrong?

Writer

```
writer.WriteStartElement("SAVED");
writer.WriteStartElement("Checkbox3");
writer.WriteString(checkBox3.Checked.ToString());
writer.WriteEndElement(); //SAVED

writer.Close();
```

Reader

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("Config.xml");
XmlNodeType type;

while (reader.Read())
{
   type = reader.NodeType;

   if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
   {
       if (reader.Name == "WindowsHost")
       {
           reader.Read();
           textBox1.Text = reader.Value;
       }
   }
   if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
   {
       if (reader.Name == "Checkbox3")
       {
           reader.Read();

           checkBox3.Checked = reader.Value; //error
       }
   }
}
reader.Close();
```

Comment: Some tips: You'd be better off doing `using (var reader = new XmlTextReader("Config.xml")) { ... }` instead of manually closing the reader at the end. Your if statements have unneeded nesting and also you could get into problems with the multiple calls of `.Read()`... may I suggest using `XDocument` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `reader.Value` is of type string, you have to parse it to `bool` before setting it to `Checked` property.

```
checkBox3.Checked = bool.Parse(reader.Value);
```